# Upvotes and Downvotes details in timeline is by-design?

Tags: discussion, timeline

Timeline can be view by anyone, so vote details in timeline is a little bit contradict with

> 1000       Show total up and down vote
>   counts

in [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), but I hope this **not** to be changed :-)

For example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40887/best-time-of-day-to-ask-question-closed) and timeline is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/40887/timeline), also a screen shot below.

[alt text http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/9461/timelinerep.gif](http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/9461/timelinerep.gif)

<sub>PS:I mean there is a work-around in timeline view to see up/down details without having 1000 reps. :-)</sub>

Comment: I see.. I completely misunderstood the question.  And good find BTW.

Comment: A good find indeed. Though I have nothing against anyone seeing the actual vote composition.

Comment: I'm Agree o.k.w, I think there is no harm in seeing up/down votes, its very helpful. I hope to keep that as is :-)

Comment: I agree no harm, but it does seem pointless to limit one to 1K users and have it available to everyone from another semi-hidden page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, now I understand your question. As far as this goes, I don't think it's too much of a problem. The 1000 rep limit is designed for several reasons:

- Use less server resources
- Be a step in between 500 and 2000 to sort of appease those who are obsessed with rep

Because of the unfamiliarity of most people with this feature, it won't use too many more server resources, since most people who know about it have >1000 rep. As for the second, someone who's determined enough will figure it out any way.

Comment: but timeline view is also available for less than 1000 rep

Comment: Not unless you link to it independently, though, right? I couldn't find a link to it on the example, but could, yes, see the timeline page once linked to. So you're talking about a permissions issue on the page itself. They're not blocking me. :)

Comment: Right, there is no link to the timeline, its on a if you know about it basis right now.

Comment: yes heavyd, but lately I made greasemonkey script and I start seeing timeline link for every questions :D, so I am just wondering it is by-design or not :-) (btw you could find that in related questions block)

Comment: Ok, answer updated. I was under the impression that @S.Mark was referring to the rep graph.